# Can an iphone app developed using html5 be sold through Apple store?

Tags: iphone

Can an iphone app developed using html5, CSS and Javascript be sold through Apple store ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can develop almost all of an app using HTML5/CSS/Javascript.  99.9% etc.

However at least a tiny portion (from a short template or a library) needs to be in Objective C to initialize a UIWebView containing the HTML web app source files, and the app bundle will need to be built using Xcode for submission to the App store.

Apple may or may not require some additional functionality beyond that of a simple web app before accepting an app into the App store.  (There have been anecdotal reports both ways.)

Answer (score 4):

**You can use a 3rd party tool like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/download/).**

*The PhoneGap mission is to Web-enable native device functionality with open standards like HTML, CSS and JavaScript so that you can focus on the app you're building, not on authoring complex platform compatibility layers.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will still to use Xcode to compile it into a iOS binary. You might need an additional framework to do this. A example is Phonegap that turns HTML into a stand alone iPhone application. It also does cool stuff (when compiled into an iOS app) like enabling GPS and Tilt sensors.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no porn, free thinking, anti-apple content or anything else Apple see's as bad for them, I don't see why not

But why wouldn't you just make it a web app?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few apps in Apple's online store that are written in HTML5.  You will need to use a framework like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) in order to compile your app, and of course your app should meet the usual Apple criteria ("we have enough fart apps").

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/webapps/

I don't know if this any help but it's a list of all the web apps on apple's website. Not sure if this is linked to app store but they do list them!